# Is it possible to use multi python version in the virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

We know we can create a virtual env by:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 ~/FOLDER-PATH/venv3
```

then in the `~/FOLDER-PATH/venv3/lib/`,  there comes the `python3.5/`

I have a question, can I create another python version under it?

I mean in the virtual env, when I active it, I can use `python2` and `python3`, `pip2`, `pip3`.

Comment: That beats *VEnv*'s purpose. Create 2 of them, each one with a *Python* version. and activate whichever you need at a given point in time.

Comment: `tox` can test the python2 and python3, what's the theory?

Comment: It creates **different** virtual environments for every test run.

Comment: do you mean create multi virtual env in one project? or when the next test, it delete the first virtual env?